# Comma separated values into select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and i'm trying to create a small app for my work but i'm stuck few days now because i have a problem and i can't find a solution.

I have 2 tables first **jobs_userac** that contains 3 fields:

```
id, user, jobsassigned
```

and the second **jobs_data** that contains 5 fields:

```
id, job_type, description, comments, client_name
```

Every row in jobs_data contain a task

```
1 - Offset  - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - Chris
2 - Plotter - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - Nick
3 - Design  - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - John
```

For every user i have one row in jobs_userac that contains the user id, username, and the assignes jobs in one field comma separated.

```
1 - Chris - 1,2
2 - Peter - 2,4,5
2 - Maria - 4
```

Every time a user is connected i store the user id into a variable $user.
I want to create a query like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data");
```

But i want to check if the connected user has a row in jobs_userac for example if the connected user is Chris to show him only the jobs from task_data where the job_type is 1 or 2
and if Maria is connected to show her the rows from jobs_data where the job_type=4.
I want to add the WHERE clause into my query and if the user has more that one  joobs assigned in jobs_userac--> jobsassigned to add the OR clause.

For user Maria

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data WHERE job_type=4");
```

For user Chris

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data WHERE job_type=1 OR job_type=2");
```

For user Peter

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data WHERE job_type=2 OR job_type=4 OR job_type=5");
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Your problem is precisely that your `job_type` *is not* "4" or "2". Your `job_type` is "2,4,5". SQL doesn't care about commas and doesn't know that you think of those numbers as separate values. Look into *normalising* your database to use a one-to-many table relationship.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Your problem is well explained for a new user. I don't know if you can change your table structure but if you can you should do it. You should create a third table which link people to their jobs. Not solve the problem but I hope it will help you. Edit: Deceze explaind it better than me :) : "_Look into normalising your database to use a one-to-many table relationship._"

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is not ideal - your `jobs_userac` should have one row per `user<->job` link.

But you can work with what you have:

```
SELECT * FROM `jobs_data` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`job_type`, "2,4,5")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for the column of user at jobs_userac whether it is storing a userId or username

here it is assuming that user are storing username or if not then kindly replace the username with the user id.

```
select * from jobs_data where IN(select jobsassigned 
                                 from jobs_userac 
                                 where user = 'Perter');
```

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally store jobsassigned of each user on connection in $jobsassigned
Now you can do the following query:

```
$queryString = 'select * from jobs_data where id IN ('.$jobsassigned.')';
```

By the way... it is better to add an extra table where you store youre relations between user and jobs

jobs

```
1 - Offset  - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - Chris
2 - Plotter - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - Nick
3 - Design  - Blablablabla - Blablablabla - John
```

users

```
1 - Chris
2 - Peter
3 - Maria
```

user_job

```
1 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 2
2 - 4
2 - 5
3 - 4
```

Answer (score 1):

As others noted your current schema is sub-optimal and generally speaking not the best way to exploit a relation data base however you can use your current structure in a query with the somewhat clumsy :

```
"SELECT * FROM JOBS_DATE WHERE id = '2' or id like '2,%' or id like '%,2,%' or id like '%,2'"
```

You need all thee likes as you have to copy with "2,5,7", "1,2,3" and "1,2" plus the equal for plain "2"

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get the job type assign to the link user:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_useracc where id=".$user);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$job_types=$row['jobassigned'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data where id IN (".$job_types.")");
```

Answer (score 0):

If each job is only every associated with one user, the id of that user should be stored against the job. so your tables should be `id, user` and `id, job_type, description, comments, client_name, user_id`. Then you can get the jobs for Chris by doing `SELECT  * FROM jobs_data WHERE user_id = 1`. This is a normal pattern for where you have many entries in one table associated with one entry in another.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `job_type` instead of `id`.

You should follow :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM jobs_data WHERE id=2 OR id=4 OR id=5");
```

And same for others i.e. use `id` at place of `job_type`.